# Can I use ? for column names in select query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, angular

I want to run query in another file so want to send sql & it's fields separately.

Can I use mysql like this :

```
module.exports.getUsers = (callback) => {
    console.log('inside server model');
    let sql = ` SELECT ?, ? FROM users `;

    var data = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    query.sqlQuery( (rows) => {
        callback(rows);
    }, sql, data);
}
```

So that resultant query will be like this:

```
let sql = ` SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users `;
```

Comment: Did you try it out? What was your result?

Comment: I was doing this with PHP all the time..

Comment: No, you cannot set column names as prepared statement values, it only works for values

Comment: You can't use param for db objects  (table name, column name)  ..  for build query this way you should take a look at dinamic sql  ( sql code string build using server side  string concatenation  )

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

If you don't want to use all values from the data array you can access array elements by position.

```
module.exports.getUsers = (callback) => {

    var data = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'postcode']

    let sql = `SELECT ${this.data[0]}, ${this.data[2]} FROM users`;

    query.sqlQuery( (rows) => {
        callback(rows);
    }, sql, data);
}
```

or if you want to all data elements

```
module.exports.getUsers = (callback) => {

    var data = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'postcode']

    let sql = `SELECT ${this.data} FROM users`;

    query.sqlQuery( (rows) => {
        callback(rows);
    }, sql, data);
}
```